# UITable cell's different view

Tags: ios, uiview, uitableview

i'm a beginner programmer and i'm currently working on a basic navigation app. I have a UITable with 3 items (for now) in my Firste level every item (cell) open another 2 items list (2 cells) in my Second level . What i want is that every 1 of this 2 items point to different view. Example: first will open some xib and the second will open some detail view . Now my second level 2 items open the same xib .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UITableViewDelegate has a method `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`
In that you could set up a switch like so:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
        {
            //do something
        } break;
        case 1:
        {
            //do something else
        } break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should really consider using UIViewController instead of using nib and views directly, as they fit the mvc model and, well, simplify your life.
You'd then subclass the tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method and open the next level view controller, whatever it would be depending of the selected cell.